# How to solve fsck.ext3: No Such file or directory on redhat 2.6.9-55

Tags: filesystems, root, redhat-enterprise-linux

I have main two problems here:

1. Error on boot. It said error file system.
2. Forgot root password.

How to solve them?

This is error occurred when boot, how to solve it while i forgot my root password :

```
Checking filesystems
fsck.ext3: No such file or directory while trying to open /dev/dsc1 [FAILED]

*** An error occurred during the file system check
*** Dropping you to a shell : the system will reboot
*** when you leave the shell.
*** Warning -- SELinux is active
*** Disabling security enforcement for system recovery
*** Run 'setenforce 1' to reeanble.
Give root password for maintenance
(or type Control-D to continue)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first question regards disk errors. It can be caused by a list of different things. I would start with [fsck and other file system tools](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/08/fsck-command-examples/), and then move on to commercial disk recovery tools afterwards (e.g. [SpinRite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpinRite)).

Your second question is [frequently asked](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Step_by_Step_Guide/s1-q-and-a-root-passwd.html).